# Как сделать post авторизацию?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string token = string.Empty;

string GenLink = "http://ask.fm/";
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(GenLink);
myRequest.Method = "GET";
myRequest.Timeout = 15000;
myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
string page = Reader.ReadToEnd();
Match res = Regex.Match(page, "var AUTH_TOKEN = \"(.*)\";");
token = res.Groups[1].ToString();
Reader.Close();
return token;

HttpWebRequest POST = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ask.fm/session");
POST.Method = "POST";
POST.Timeout = 15000;
POST.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
POST.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string data = "authenticity_token="+token+"&login=vk_groups&password=363534qwa&follow=&like=&back=&authenticity_token="+token;
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
POST.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
Stream stream = POST.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
string response = new StreamReader(POST.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Пытаюсь сделать вот так, но не получается ничего. Вот что отправляется:

```
authenticity_token=WWRqTElVSCMg4LvjrQVq%2BgjmDZ%2BjbVcM3LBPTGZHhLQ%3D&login=volodiaklicko2&password=&follow=&like=&back=&authenticity_token=WWRqTElVSCMg4LvjrQVq%2BgjmDZ%2BjbVcM3LBPTGZHhLQ%3D ----
```

Comment: у меня один маленький глупый вопрос - вы тут в коде выложили свой логин-пароль. Это так надо, или...?

Comment: это тестовый аккаунт, который мне не столь важен) если кто-то всё-таки решит помочь, то чтоб не тратить время на регистрацию, может воспользоваться моим аккаунтом, нужна помощь очень срочно))

Comment: ну хорошо. теперь собственно к вопросу. Вы говорите "пытаюсь сделать вот так, но не получается ничего". Какое именно "ничего" у вас не получается?

Comment: ну вставьте мой код в консоль, и увидите, что выводится токен, и никаких уведомлений о том, что я авторизовался, следовательно, авторизация не произошла. Я не знаю, как правильно сделать post запрос для авторизации, потому что ещё не силён в области запросов) поэтому прошу помощи в составлении запроса на авторизацию

Comment: как я понимаю, я должен создать запрос и при компилировании в консоли должно появиться уведомление о том, что я авторизовался. я уверен на 100% что в своём post запросе я ещё что-то должен написать для авторизации))) но я не знаю чего именно в нём не хватает

Comment: так, подождите, что значит "авторизация не произошла"? Я не знаю, что это за сервис, и как он предполагает устраивать аутентификацию, поэтому сложно сказать, чего вы именно от него ждете. Пока что я вижу, что вы делаете запрос и получаете ответ, который содержит некий токен. Опять же повторю, я не знаю механизмов аутентификации этого ресурса, однако же по аналогии с другими подобными, получив токен, вы можете им пользоваться. Или вы ждете чего-то еще кроме токена?

Comment: "authenticity_token=WWRqTElVSCMg4LvjrQVq%2BgjmDZ%2BjbVcM3LBPTGZHhLQ%3D&login=volodiaklicko2&password=&follow=&like=&back=&authenticity_token=WWRqTElVSCMg4LvjrQVq%2BgjmDZ%2BjbVcM3LBPTGZHhLQ%3D " <– вот так выглядит сам запрос на сайте. Если вы в браузере нажмёте F12 и перейдёте в раздел "сеть", то увидите, как работает этот ресурс. Я получаю токен, для того чтоб передать его в post запрос, но при передаче ничего не происходит => я что-то ещё должен учесть либо как-то по-другому это всё реализовать, но не знаю как

Answer (score 1):

так, подождите. Я посмотрел повнимательнее ваш код, и тут есть несколько вопросов.

Вы  там пишете два запроса, причем первый из них вообще не несет в себе никакой логики авторизации - вы просто обращаетесь к этому ask.fm. В ответе вы получаете html-код главной страницы сайта. Затем с помощью регулярки выдергиваете из этого кода некую переменную, называнную AUTH_TOKEN  (он просто вшит в текст js скрипта прямым текстом). Я не знаю, что это за токен, но в любом случае это не тот токен авторизации, который вы можете получить при корректной авторизации, это всего лишь кусо js-скрипта, которому вряд ли можно доверять. Поэтому то, что вы получаете в итоге у вас и не работает.

Затем вы выполняете еще один запрос, и в нем тоже очень странная логика. Вы запрашиваете код страницы http://ask.fm/session и в ответе получаете его, как и в случае с педыдущим запросом - со всеми тэгами, скриптами и прочим.  Однако и этот запрос тоже не несет в себе логики авторизации - вы просто получаете содержимое страницы и пишете его в поток.

Если у этого сайта есть api, как например у многих соцсетей, то воспользуйтесь им. Если такового нет, то вам нужно шаманить с парсингом страниц, впрочем, это довольно муторное и ненадежное занятие

Comment: вы с этим делом сможете мне помочь? Авторизацию сделать

Comment: @inkorpus1 заниматься парсингом страниц я бы не хотел - это утомительное и довольно скучное занятие. Поэтому советовал бы вам узнать о наличии api сайта

Comment: у этого сайта нет api

Comment: @inkorpus1: Тогда вам придётся провести reverse engineering системы авторизации на сайте. Good luck!